# Prevent treeset from removing index if compared value exists?

Tags: java, list, loops

I have an highscores system, and to display ranks I need users to be sorted by double (the rank) in the list.

So i did this:

```
private TreeSet<PlayerScore> players = new TreeSet<PlayerScore>();
```

PlayerScore:

```
public class PlayerScore implements Comparable<PlayerScore> {

    private final TempClient client;
    private final double kdr;

    public PlayerScore(TempClient client, double kdr) {
        this.client = client;
        this.kdr = kdr;
    }

    public int hashCode() { 
        return this.client.hashCode(); 
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) { 
        return this == o; 
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(PlayerScore o) {
        return Double.compare(this.kdr, o.kdr);
    }

    public TempClient getClient() {
        return this.client;
    }

    public double getKdr() {
        return this.kdr;
    }

}
```

And for testing, to add value i do this:

```
    TempClient client = new TempClient(96, "D", 46, "gh");
    this.players.add(new PlayerScore(client, client.getKdr()));
    TempClient client2 = new TempClient(96, "D", 46, "gh");
    this.players.add(new PlayerScore(client2, client2.getKdr()));
```

See how the 96 value is the same? now let's iterate..

```
    for (PlayerScore s : players) {
        System.out.println("Playername: " + s.getClient().getName() + " " + s.getKdr());
    }
```

Output: `[6/01/14 9:01 PM]: Playername: gh 0.0`
I also did size check, size = 1.

How can I not make the list remove if value already exists? can't it somehow make it go below it? Like most highscores system do?

Comment: Sets and repetition don't really go together.

Comment: In other words, TreeSet is probably a poor choice of data structure.

Comment: +1 go with some kind of list sir. Anything with the word Set in it isn't good for dupes http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html "A collection that contains no duplicate elements"

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your Comparator so that players with the same score do not compare to 0, for example:

```
public int compareTo(PlayerScore o) {
    return this.kdr != o.kdr
           ? Double.compare(this.kdr, o.kdr)
           : this.client.compareTo(o.client);
}
```

If `TempClient` does not implement `Comparable`, you can randomly return a non 0 value:

```
public int compareTo(PlayerScore o) {
    return this.kdr != o.kdr
           ? Double.compare(this.kdr, o.kdr)
           : 1;
}
```

Note: your `equals` method is useless: it is exactly the same as `Object#equals`...

Answer (score 0):

You need to override your equals and comparison method so it is equals only if both the score is the same and the playername matches.

Then when adding a new score to the set first remove the old score version of that player then add the new score version.